# graph theory proof or disproving

Tags: graphs

I was requested to prove or disprove the following statement 
if a graph is conncted does it necessarily means that E>(V-1)(V-2)/2
v  represents vertex and E the edges
I think I need to disprove it with overall disproval but how?

Answer (score 1):

If you think it's false, the easiest way to disprove it would be to find a counterexample. That is, find a graph where $E \leq \frac{1}{2}(V-1)(V-2)$. Try some easy connected graphs (e.g. a straight-line path graph) and see if you can find a suitable graph.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're talking about the graph being a simple graph. In that case:

For a connected graph, $e \geq v - 1$. Therefore, in the worst case, your statement would be true if $v - 1 > \frac{(v - 1)(v - 2)}{2}$.

The inequality reduces to $(v - 1)(v - 4) < 0$, which means that the possible values of $v$ for the statement to be true are $2$ and $3$. 
For all $v$ that are not are equal to $2$ or $3$, your statement won't hold true.

So, the statement is not true for all values of $v$.

EDIT: If you want direct counter-examples, consider any connected simple graph with 4 vertices. That'd be a counter-example.